# ZyXEL switch management port configuration

Tags: networking, port, switch, zyxel

I'm a total newbie in configuring a network switch and I would like to know how can I configure the management port of a ZyXEL switch.

I have a ZyXEL XGS3700-24 model and I set an IP address like 192.168.3.X where the web interface answer and I can connect with a browser, entering with admin user.

Since I have a management port I tried to configure it with an IP address on a different subnet (192.168.4.X) but when I try to connect to that port I can't reach it.

I wonder if I missed something when I first configured the MGMT port, into the "IP Setup" menu I set the IP address, the subnet mask and the gateway address, there's also a field as "Default Management" where I can set "in-band" or "out-of-band" value but I don't know which is the right setup.

Please could someone give me a little explanation of how a ZyXEL MGMT port works and how can I configure it?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but the first result from this Google search is the user manual for that switch, which explains those settings, which is where you should have gone first for your answer. - https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ZyXEL+XGS3700-24+manual

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with that model but your question depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to be able to manage it from the current network in use? If so, use the in-band option. If you got a seperate management network which is separate from the "regular" traffic, use the out-of-band option.

When you tried setting the IP address and tried connecting to it, were you directly connected to the management port? If so, you are 100% sure you were on the same IP-network and subnet as the management-port itself? Did the gateway you specified actually exist for that specific network?

The manual for your switch states it already configures the management-port by default to 192.168.0.1 out-of-bound and webUI in-band 192.168.1.1.

Regarding the "default management" bit; it seems like it's used to decide where traffic like SNMP and other traffic originating from the switch itself should go (and unknown source). The first part of the description describes it a bit dependant on what you want to achieve.

If this is just for testing purposes, and you don't have a management network supporting the out-of-bound management I would have tried configuring the "Management IP Address" section like this:

```
IP Address: 192.168.3.10
Subnet-mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: <blank>
```

You then should be able to reach it if you connect your computer directly to the out-of-bands management port and set the adress on your computer to be on the same network (192.168.3.x with 255.255.255.0 mask and no gateway).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation xstnc! When I was directly connected to the management port it worked. I'll try to configure it with the in-band option as I would like to manage it from my network.

Comment: You're welcome! If that's the case, I would dig into how the rest of the network is setup considering the diffrent subnets and so on. Perhaps its own management-network for out-of-band is in order, with its own gateway? :)

Comment: I confirm that is working correctly with in-band configuration and even with the outband if I connect directly to the MGMT port on a different subnet :)